# Show Certain Programs Depending On Certain Months

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, ruby-on-rails-4

I am setting up an app that has certain programs that a user can subscribe to. These programs start and stop consecutively (example program A runs form Jan-March, program B runs to April-June, program C runs July-September and program D runs from October-December).

I would like to only display the programs open for subscribers when the month is present for the specific program or programs.

What is the proper method (Built in or to create) to set up in my views? I have read through the Ruby Date Api Docs (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html) but didnt find anything to suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your program model has a start date and an end date. You would compare the current time (DateTime.current or Time.current) against those to determine which program to show. You could define a helper method or a scope on Program to return the appropriate program based on the current time.

You can get your current quarter with this approach:

`current_quarter = ((Time.now.month - 1) / 3) + 1`

and then basically you leverage that to set the start and end date on a scope/helper method to filter your programs.

Comment: Just for reference though: even though I do have a program start date and an end date in my model, is there a way to set it up without those columns in your database something like : (if Date.today.strftime("%m") == January || Feburary || March) [My View Here] (end)

Comment: Sure thing, but you would still need to map the association between the program and the quarter / period (ie program X should show during the 4th quarter) in your database, so it ends up being similar in nature.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is you want a program that run automatically on a special date, This gem may solve your problem.

https://github.com/javan/whenever

Comment: Ahh Not exactly,  I don't think I need a cron job. Basically what I'm looking for is if today's Month is Jan-March only program A should be shown in the views (same for each program dependng on the month). I already have the programs in my code now I just want to limit a users ability to see and subscribe to programs depending on the Month